# searching for expletives in visual studio projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am still in the stage of trying to not write expletive comments to myself, so on project completion I do a search for the main "abused" words.

Are the Microsoft devs filthy mouthed or is it coincedence?

(* = removed letter)

```
D:\Projects......resx(3996):        8g7fqR/cfvvt386D/zGF1TYJfIB5weKlYcESxrKwcKlUcU*tpdF5VrGvpYZHiS1VfD12tuzm9Zs3SyVn

D:\Projects\.....resx(3706):        L6QEuEi5sMzyh24/noC5wqUC*NTXlQPWqr62XJCX8nrbw8D3TWUEJYkisCnDNDu0KYPqAL/UEIC/yZqA

 D:\Projects\....resx(7349):        aKtRVgW2niEevp/n4XhGaMqS941TpuzAEbXSbIVlIgJ8mPZDf3Cp2qvY9WrTpd8vPAtOF*cK34BGgRYg

D:\Projects\....resx(1963):        GYDa2oFR45PBMFZ9tcDfU*KmjQLw0eMn7PX4mny9seuYwA3QDeQyi96k5ltz625fhxcDXFGb6O2tyijO

D:\Projects\....resx(2247):        8kotbWCBQzzDPVRz9b1691MLa4uWM8oB5NXcMbFWc*CkpL48XtyQo1JL0vJgrjupuYPRT9/vDvvcOBPE
```

Comment: The [clbuttic](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Clbuttic-Mistake-.aspx) problem...

Answer (score 3):

The answer is one of:

- Yes
- No

We'll give them the benefit of the doubt and say most likely no, these are just random.